# How do you use Blender to make Pokemon attacks like hyper beam and solar beam?

Tags: animation, particles

I can't figure out how to use Blender to make beam moves, like an energy beam. Any tutorials or advice?

*From the Title:*

[image]

Solar beam

[image]

Hyper beam

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! I think you should try to be more precise in your request: there are multiple way in which those beams were drawn/animated, which one you are referring? Could you post an image/link a video? And what effect can't you reproduce exactly? The ray motion, the flares, the glare, the energy wave's flickering...?

Answer (score 4):

Never tried to create any effect like that, but it is possible that particles are not the most effective way to simulate those beams.

Have you tried looking into create "Plasma Wave" effects like these using geometry instead? Like [Abstract Waves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pau2HJsIF7U) or [Plasma Waves](https://vimeo.com/86520821) or [any other](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=vid&hl=en&lr=lang_en%7Clang_pt&q=blender%20plasma)

Perhaps actually modeling it with geometry might be easier. Adding some effects over it, like added particles, volumetric materials, or even in post production, like glow and blur may improve the final aspect.

Comment: That looks like it should work! thanks so much dude!